# Setting div to a percentage up until a certain amount of pixels?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to set an element's width to a percentage up until it reaches a certain amount of pixels?

For example: A button on a window that should extend a width of 95% up until the window (or button, either solution is fine), if expanded, reaches 700 pixels and then will stop expanding?

Comment: Look at the `max-width` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could set a maximum width on the button.

```
button {
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 95%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at media queries

for example: 
`@media screen and (min-width:500px) { ... }`

For more information you can look here
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: this is a good working solution, but I felt it was more straight forward to use a regular css max-with rule without making a media query

Answer (score 0):

You just use the max-width CSS property

```
max-width:800px
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bdobx0b1/

```
.maxWidth {
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <button class="maxWidth">click</button>
```